# How to mock api response with testcafe?

Tags: automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

I'm trying to mock the response from graphql api.
I can see that the requests are sent but the response is always the same. I only get back the response from response1.

```
RequestMock()
.onRequestTo({url:"https://test.net/graphql?locale=en-US&co=GB"
        , method: 'POST'
        , body: {
            operationName: "getCount",
            variables: {
               
            },
            query: "query GetCount {}")
.respond(response1)
.onRequestTo({url:"https://test.net/graphql?locale=en-US&co=GB"
        , method: 'POST'
        , body: {
            operationName: "getItem",
            variables: {
               
            },
            query: "query GetItem {}")
.respond(response2)
.onRequestTo({url:"https://test.net/graphql?locale=en-US&co=GB"
        , method: 'POST'
        , body: {
            operationName: "getData",
            variables: {
               
            },
            query: "query GetData {}")
.respond(response3)
```

In the examples shown here
https://testcafe.io/documentation/402762/reference/test-api/requestmock/respond

They have different urls.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the method with the predicate argument. Refer to the following article for more details: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402763/reference/test-api/requestmock/onrequestto#filter-with-a-predicate.